# Como adicionar reticências caso o conteúdo vaze do layout do Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Como adicionar reticências caso o conteúdo vaze do layout do Android?

Por exemplo:
Tenho um texto muito grande na minha *ActionBar*, e em vez de ter que diminui-lo de tamanho, quero que ele adicione reticências caso haja vazamento de layout, por exemplo, de "Primeiros Socorros" para "Primeiros Soc..."

Comment: Tente limitar o tamanho do seu TextView utilizando a medida :ems

Comment: utilizei o ems, mas ele quebra a linha do texto!

Comment: Como faço para ele excluir o texto que estoura o tamanho, alterando por reticencias

Answer (score 3):

O `TextView` possui um atributo chamado `ellipsize`, o qual, [segundo a documentacao](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize), permite que a adicao dos `...` automaticamente caso a palavra seja muito grande, ao invés de quebrar no meio.

No seu caso, utilize o atributo `android:ellipsize="end"` em seu `TextView`, juntamente com `android:singleLine="true"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```